# C# reg express: how to remove parentheses from a number

Tags: c#, regex

I need to remove parentheses from a phone number as below. But with following code I can only remove spaces. 
How can I improve this method to clean the phone string from all other possible chars?

Cheers

```
 string phone = "(123)234 5566"; //(+954)123 3456
 string phone = prep_numbers(@"/[^0-9]/", "", phone);

 public static string prep_numbers(string pattern, string replacement, string subject)
    {
        string str = Regex.Replace(subject, pattern, replacement);
        str = str.Replace(" ", String.Empty);
        return str;
    }
```

Comment: Use `prep_numbers("[^0-9]", "", phone);` ([demo](https://ideone.com/LL5rlP)). C# regex notation does not support regex delimiters, `/` are part of the pattern in your regex.

Comment: `Regex.Replace(phone, "[^0-9]", "")`

Comment: `phone = string.Concat(phone.Where(c => c >= '0' && c <= '9'));`

Comment: Thank you @WiktorStribiżew and Pawel this is perfectly working.